# Event Register Issue

Tags: civievent, wordpress, upgrade

WP 4.4, PHP 5.5

Upgraded CiviCRM to 4.6.10 and now getting white screen when on final step of event registration - Confirm

PHP error shows:

`Fatal error: Smarty error: [in string:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <title></title> </head> <body> {capture assign=headerStyle}colspan="2" style="text-align: left; padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #eee;"{/capture} {capture assign=labelStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #f7f7f7;"{/capture} {capture assign=valueStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999;"{/capture} {capture assign=tdfirstStyle}style="width: 180px; padding-bottom: 15px;"{/capture} {capture assign=tdStyle}style="width: 100px;"{/capture} {capture assign=participantTotal}style="margin: 0.5em in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094`

Comment: Have you cleared caches after the upgrade?